# Bug with Prototype 1.7.1 and Native Array Usage

Tags: javascript, exception, prototypejs

Using chrome 21 and prototype 1.7.1, I have discovered that using `throw $break` does not work.

The `Error` gets thrown up to the browser when it should have been stopped by

```
if (e != $break) { ... }
```

I suspect that this occurs because `inject` has a native implementation in Chrome, and it does not get wrapped by the same functionality as the other built-in functions.

Am I correct when assuming this, or is there something wrong with my code?

Code to [re-create](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/Dxefg/):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9].inject([], function(arr, e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (e === 5) {
        throw $break;
    }

    arr.push('Done ' + e);
    return arr;
});
console.log('Final Array : ' + a)
```

**update**

just tested with Firefox 14 and IE 9, the same error presents itself..

​**update (2015)**

This seems to be fixed by `1.7.3`, tested with Chrome 45.0.2454.101

Verified by checking the source, `reduce` was removed

Comment: I found [this newsgroup thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/prototype-scriptaculous/vQNk3L4jJfE) where `$break` is mentioned as deprecated

Comment: mmh, it's weird that is is not in any documentation and there are no workarounds (that I know of), have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that as of Prototype 1.7.1, `Array#inject` has two implementations, and they behave differently. (This is Not Good<sup>tm</sup>.) It's a breaking change between Prototype 1.7.1 and 1.7.0, as we can see using [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxefg/2/) vs. [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/Dxefg/3/).

If the native `Array` object has the `reduce` function from ES5, `Array#inject` uses it — without handling `$break` — whereas if it doesn't, `Array#inject` is implemented via `Enumerable#inject`, which uses `Enumerable#each`, which handles `$break`.

You can see this if you search the Prototype 1.7.1 source. First you find the non-`reduce` version in `Enumerable`, then you find the `reduce` version further down in the `Array` stuff, and you see that the `Array` version grabs the `Enumerable` version if `reduce` isn't there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there anyway to remedy this cross-code, cross-browser without changing my code?

Comment: After loading Prototype, you can do `Array.prototype.inject = Enumerable.inject;`

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and concise explanation, I will revert to `1.7.0` until a better approach becomes available